# Character encoding using Scanner in Java

Tags: windows, encoding, polish

I'm trying to read a file containing polish characters using Java and then print it in the command line in windows (english version).

This is the text I want to read:

Minister Ziobro polecił Prokuraturze Okręgowej w Płocku wszczęcie odrębnego śledztwa w sprawie o zabójstwo.

This is the output:

Minister Ziobro poleci│ Prokuraturze OkrÛgowej w P│ocku wszczÛcie odrÛbnego £ledztwa w sprawie o zab¾jstwo.

I'm using the UTF-8 encoding:

String encoding = "UTF-8";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fFileName), encoding);

I changed all settings in "Regional and Language Options" to polish but it didn't work.
When I load this text into gedit all characters are displayed correctly.